# Implement this "Magma" trait easily without a wrapper

Tags: types, rust, wrapper, traits

My goal was to create a function that convert an element of type `Couple<Couple<Couple<T>>>` to something of type `T`

Most of the time, that seams really easy to do. In fact, if you have an operator or a function that combine 2 `T` into 1 `T`, you can do it recursively.

```
If I want to fusion ((1 2) (3 4)) into a single number, 
I can use the "+" operator recursively:
(1 + 2) + (3 + 4) = 10
```

So I created a trait called [Magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) (a type with a combining operation), and a function to fusion recursively a couple with this trait.

```rust
// simple couple type
struct Couple<T>(T, T);

trait Magma {
    // a magma is just a type with a function   (S, S) -> S (for ex. the "+" operation)
    fn combine(a: Self, b: Self) -> Self;
}

// fn fusion<T>(Couple<Couple<Couple<T>>>) -> T where T: Magma {}
```

But the thing is, to use this `fusion` function with for example a `Couple<Couple<bool>>` type, I have to implement `Magma` for `bool`

```rust
impl Magma for bool {
    fn combine(a: bool, b: bool) -> bool {
        a && b
    }
}
```

But they are many ways you can combine 2 booleans to get 1: "or", "and", "xor" ...

And I cannot implement `Magma` for every one of these functions !

So my current approach is to use wrappers around bools:

```rust
struct OrWrapper(bool);

impl Magma for OrWrapper {
    fn combine(a: Self, b:Self) -> Self {
        OrWrapper(a.0 || b.0)
    }
}


struct AndWrapper(bool);

impl Magma for AndWrapper{
    fn combine(a: Self, b:Self) -> Self {
        AndWrapper(a.0 && b.0)
    }
}
```

But it is really repetitive and painfull to write, I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: "magma"? "fusion"? By your wording these sound like terms with specific meaning. Is this following some existing pattern?

Comment: You're right I will edit to explain them

Comment: @kmdreko A [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) is an algebraic term, which is a generalisation of group, monoid, semigroup etc.

Comment: @rambi The wrapper approach is exactly how this is done in Haskell. See: https://wiki.haskell.org/Monoid. I don't think there is a better approach, since the structure is by definition a combination of a set and an operator. You need to encode that operator somehow in the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wrapper type is almost certainly the way to go. A magma is defined as a pair: a set (i.e. the type) and an operator, and you have to capture both of them somehow.

You can change your `Magma` trait to make it more convenient to use, so it can accept the inner types and convert to the wrapper internally:

```
trait Magma: Sized {
    fn combine(self, b: impl Into<Self>) -> Self;
}
```

If the repetition of defining these wrapper types is what you are worried about then you can use a macro to generate them:

```
macro_rules! magma {
    ($($ty: ty as $wrapper: ident => $op: path),* $(,)?) => {
        $(
            // a new wrapper type
            #[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
            pub struct $wrapper($ty);
            
            impl Magma for $wrapper {
                fn combine(self, b: impl Into<Self>) -> $wrapper {
                    $wrapper($op(&self.0, &b.into().0))
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}

magma! {
    bool as BoolAnd => std::ops::BitAnd::bitand,
    bool as BoolOr => std::ops::BitOr::bitor,
    u32 as U32Add => std::ops::Add::add,
    u32 as U32Mul => std::ops::Mul::mul,
}
```

For further convenience, you may want to also implemnt `From` conversions, `Deref` and possibly other traits like `Display` for these types:

```
macro_rules! magma {
    ($($ty: ty as $wrapper: ident => $op: path),* $(,)?) => {
        $(
            // a new wrapper type
            #[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
            pub struct $wrapper($ty);
            
            // conversion from the raw type to the wrapper
            impl From<$ty> for $wrapper {
                fn from(x: $ty) -> $wrapper { $wrapper(x) }
            }
            
            // conversion from the wrapper type to the inner type
            impl From<$wrapper> for $ty {
                fn from(w: $wrapper) -> $ty { w.0 }
            }
            
            // Deref to the inner type for convenience
            impl std::ops::Deref for $wrapper {
                type Target = $ty;
                fn deref(&self) -> &$ty { &self.0 }
            }
            
            // Delegate to the inner type for display
            impl std::fmt::Display for $wrapper {
                fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                    self.0.fmt(f)
                }
            }
            
            impl Magma for $wrapper {
                fn combine(self, b: impl Into<Self>) -> $wrapper {
                    $wrapper($op(&self.0, &b.into().0))
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
magma! {
    bool as BoolAnd => std::ops::BitAnd::bitand,
    bool as BoolOr => std::ops::BitOr::bitor,
    u32 as U32Add => std::ops::Add::add,
    u32 as U32Mul => std::ops::Mul::mul,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", BoolOr(true).combine(false)); // true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to that from Peter Hall is to create a type that combines the value and operation - and uses a zero-sized type for the operation. This means the need for macros is reduced.

Using traits like Peters, this might look like:

```
trait Magma: Sized {
    fn combine(self, b: impl Into<Self>) -> Self;
}

trait ExternalMagma<T> {
    fn combine(a: T, b: T) -> T;
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct ValueWithOp<T,F: ExternalMagma<T>>(T, F);

impl<T, F> Magma for ValueWithOp<T, F>
where
    F: ExternalMagma<T>
{
    fn combine(self, b: impl Into<Self>) -> Self {
        let f = self.1;
        ValueWithOp(F::combine(self.0, b.into().0), f)
    }
}

impl<T,F> From<T> for ValueWithOp<T,F>
where F: Default + ExternalMagma<T>
{
    fn from(v:T) -> ValueWithOp<T,F> {
        ValueWithOp(v, F::default())
    }
}

impl<T,F> ValueWithOp<T,F>
where F: ExternalMagma<T> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Default)]
struct BoolOrOp;
impl ExternalMagma<bool> for BoolOrOp {
   fn combine(a: bool, b: bool) -> bool { a || b }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Default)]
struct MulOp;
impl ExternalMagma<f32> for MulOp {
   fn combine(a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 { a * b }
}
impl ExternalMagma<i32> for MulOp {
   fn combine(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 { a * b }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", ValueWithOp::<bool, BoolOrOp>::from(true).combine(false).unwrap() ); // true
    println!("{}", ValueWithOp::<i32, MulOp>::from(2).combine(3).unwrap() ); // 6
}
```

You can see this on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=96a1f16578de04396c2d9e9c9fa6de31):

Comment: This doesn't work for my use case: I can't combine a "ValueWithOp(1, +)" and a "ValueWithOp(2, ×)". But this is exactly what I needed to do (and this struct seems a bit meaningless for me)